# How can Grid.Row attached property coerce its value to row count when the value is greater than it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, dependency-properties

I know that all elements inside WPF Grid is placed into rows by using `Grid.Row` attached property. If an element inside Grid doesn't set Row attached property, that property set to zero by default. See the `RowProperty` definition below:

```
//Grid.cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty RowProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                  "Row",
                  typeof(int),
                  typeof(Grid),
                  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                          0,
                          new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCellAttachedPropertyChanged)),
                  new ValidateValueCallback(IsIntValueNotNegative));
```

So far I understand the mechanism well. But when it comes to set Grid.Row attached property of an element inside Grid to a value greater than `RowDefinition` count, the element is placed in last row. This is what I don't understand. How is the `RowProperty` be coerced to the RowDefinition count of Grid? 
There is no `CoerceValueCallback` in the RowProperty DP definition to coerce value to row count if it is out of range.
To illustrate what I am trying to say:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">      
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="My Content" Grid.Row="10"/>
</Grid>
```

Label is placed in the last row(2nd position) even if I set its Row to 10. No exception thrown by the compiler. What is the magic behind this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's any *magic* behind this at all, the designer of the `Grid` simply decided that if you set the `Grid.Row` attached property to be greater than the number of rows, then the element will appear in the **last** row. Unless I'm completely missing your question?

Comment: I couldn't find anything about in `Grid.cs` how to place that element in last row. This is what is my problem :)

Comment: You may look at ValidateCellsCore method.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. This is what I want.

Comment: Allright, why is allowed to set a value to `Grid.Row` greater than row count? Is there any benefit? Any ideas?